# how to use gem doc_ripper with external links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I am trying to use the [doc_ripper](https://github.com/pzaich/doc_ripper) gem and as per whats written all the requirements work fine.

What I am trying to implement is that instead of path to local file, I would like to include path to url of the file.

When I tried to run the command --> DocRipper::rip('/path/to/file')
for the external link it gave me the following error

```
DocRipper::rip(s3storageurl)
NoMethodError: undefined method `rip' for nil:NilClass
```

I would like to know if anybody is using the above gem and is able to pass urls

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Comment: @Disha hi. Have not found the solution for the above. So we had to go for another gem --> msworddoc-extractor

Comment: Okay.Thanks @Sagar